# How can I select the most recent unique record based on another column for each ID in SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I'm having the following issue, using Snowflake SQL.

I have a table with many columns, including User_ID, Event, USD_Amount, Date.

There are many duplicate columns, and I am thus trying to write a query which will return all the columns in this table, but only only one (most recent) row for each Event of each User_ID.

For example:

| User_ID | Event | Date | USD_Amount | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432980 | Closed Account | 2021-01-30 15:30:10 | ... | .... |
| 434092 | Logged In | 2021-01-30 14:20:15 | ... | .... |
| 432980 | Created Account | 2021-01-20 11:45:25 | ... | .... |
| 432980 | Created Account | 2021-01-20 11:45:25 | ... | .... |
| 434092 | Created Account | 2021-01-19 10:30:05 | ... | .... |
| 434092 | Created Account | 2021-01-19 10:30:05 | ... | .... |

I'd want to return:

| User_ID | Event | Date | USD_Amount | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 432980 | Closed Account | 2021-01-30 15:30:10 | ... | .... |
| 434092 | Logged In | 2021-01-30 14:20:15 | ... | .... |
| 432980 | Created Account | 2021-01-20 11:45:25 | ... | .... |
| 434092 | Created Account | 2021-01-19 10:30:05 | ... | .... |
| 491831 | Logged Out | 2021-01-19 10:10:00 | ... | .... |
| 491831 | Created Account | 2021-01-18 20:18:40 | ... | .... |

I haven't found a similar question on StackOverflow and have only figured out solutions for this, such as using a partition or a sub-select when selecting the most recent row for each User_ID, not taking into account Event or another column. I am not sure how to do this taking into account more than just the User_ID and Date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i suggest you to use [this tool](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/querybuilder/)

Answer (score 3):

[QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html) allows you to run a filter after all the other stages of the WHERE/GROUPBY have completed. So pairing that with ROW_NUMBER() partitioned over the partitions, and order in descending, so the newest date is the first, we can the "select to keep" only that row:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by User_ID, Event order by date desc) = 1;
```

Which is the same as Lemon's second example thus `WHERE rank = 1`, but more compact.